# Possible to put a conditional statement inside a here document?

Tags: ruby, heredoc

I know we can do things like this:

```
puts <<START
----Some documents
#{if true
"yesyesyesyesyesyesyesyesyesyes"
else
"nonononononononononononononono"
end}
----Some documents
START
```

But is it possible to do like this:

```
puts <<START
----Some documents
#{if true}
yesyesyesyesyesyesyesyesyesyes
#{else}
nonononononononononononononono
#{end}
----Some documents
START
```

Why I want this is because I hate single/double-quotes in here document, avoiding them will make the document clearer

anyone can help?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you actually want to use ERB if the intention is to perform templating.  ERB will support splitting the if/else fine:

```
require 'erb'

template = ERB.new <<-DOC
----Some documents
<% if true %>
yesyesyesyesyesyesyesyesyesyes
<% else %>
nonononononononononononononono
<% end %>
----Some documents
DOC

string = template.result(binding)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could consider nested heredocs:

```
puts <<EOF
---- Some documents
#{if true; <<WHENTRUE
yesyesyes
WHENTRUE
else <<WHENFALSE
nonono
WHENFALSE
end
}---- Some documents
EOF
```

Note that you need to place the closing `}` on the beginning of the line or you will have an extra empty line.

**Edit:** You could avoid that and perhaps get a bit nicer syntax by using a little helper function:

```
def if_text(condition, whentrue, whenfalse)
  (condition ? whentrue : whenfalse).chomp
end

puts <<EOF
---- Some documents
#{if_text(true, <<ELSE, <<ENDIF)
yesyesyes
ELSE
nonono
ENDIF
}
---- Some documents
EOF
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll give the alternative I would favour, which is to use heredocs assigned to variables that are then inserted in a master heredoc, as it gets the conditional outside of the heredoc, thus giving the better clarity you're looking for (especially when things start getting more complicated than a contrived example):

```
cond = if true
<<TRUE
yesyesyesyesyesyesyesyesyesyes
TRUE
else
<<NOTTRUE
nonononononononononononononono
NOTTRUE
end.strip

puts <<START
----Some documents
#{cond}
----Some documents
START
```

If you're looking for a template then there are plenty out there, and plenty better than ERB in my opinion (start with looking at Haml).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`ERB`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html) if you really wanted something like that:

```
str = <<-ERB
----Some documents
<% if true %>
yesyesyesyesyesyesyesyesyesyes
<% else %>
nonononononononononononononono
<% end %>
----Some documents
ERB
erb = ERB.new(str, nil, '<>');
puts erb.result(binding)
```